# How to check if a rectangular prism is fully nested within another, including rotation

Tags: java, geometry, collision-detection

The isNesting method in `Box` is responsible for checking if one box instance is fully nested inside of another, by checking if each dimension is within the bounds of the parent box. [Example of a return true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkUW.jpg).  [Example of a return false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfXSo.jpg).

```java
class Box {

  private float width;
  private float height;
  private float length;

  Box(float width, float height, float length) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.length = length;
  }
  public boolean isNesting(Box outsideBox) {
    if(this.length <= outsideBox.length && this.width <= outsideBox.width && this.height <= outsideBox.height)
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  public Box biggerBox(Box oldBox) {
    return new Box(1.25f*oldBox.getWidth(), 1.25f*oldBox.getHeight(), 1.25f*oldBox.getLength());
  }

  public Box smallerBox(Box oldBox) {
    return new Box(.25f*oldBox.getWidth(), .25f*oldBox.getHeight(), .25f*oldBox.getLength());
  }
}
```

However, the issue here is that this method doesn't cover different rotations that smallerBox or baseBox might have.  How would I incorporate this logic?

```java
class BoxTester {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Box baseBox = new Box(2.5f, 5.0f, 6.0f);
    Box biggerBox = baseBox.biggerBox(baseBox);
    Box smallerBox = baseBox.smallerBox(baseBox);

    System.out.println(baseBox.isNesting(smallerBox));
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the `Rectangle` class. It implements a `contains(...)` method.

Comment: Is there a way I could get the behavior I want without fundamentally changing my current code, or using another class?

Comment: Actually the Rectangle class is 2D. It looks like your code is 3D, so the suggestion won't work.

Comment: And you can't just check the lengths.  A `4.5' x .25" x .25"` inner box must be tilted to fit in a  `3' by 4' x 1"` outer box.

Answer (score 0):

Sort dimensions for both cuboids.

Compare corresponding dimensions in order.

```
 public boolean isNesting(Box outsideBox) {
    if(this.dim[0] <= outsideBox.dim[0] && this.dim[1] <= outsideBox.dim[1] && this.dim[2] <= outsideBox.dim[2])
        return true;
```

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the problem.  Isn't this just another way of storing the box dimensions?  How does this solve for different rotations?

Comment: So your box might be not axis-aligned?